# go backwards through img slider jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I made a little img slider using jQuery with prev and next buttons. The slider advances automatically, the next button also works, but the prev button is wonky... Here's a link to the jsfiddle since its a little long:

http://jsfiddle.net/davidpm/5TsL6/

...and the obligatory snippet:

```
var sliderCentral = {                             

  nextImage: function(d) {
          var index = currIndex + d;

          if (index <= 0) {       
            index = totalImg;       
          };
          if (index >= totalImg) {        // totalImg = 4
            index = 0;
          };
          currIndex = index;   
          $slider.fadeIn(500);  
  },
```

I've commented out where I think the issues are. This should be a quick fix (for someone who knows what they're doing)... Any help?

Thanks in advance,

-D

Comment: There was some issue with the advancing and retarding the `currIndex`.  See: http://jsfiddle.net/moob/5TsL6/4/

Comment: May this helps: http://jsfiddle.net/drjj7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is the solution: [Jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/2cRVk/1/)

```
       nextImage: function (d) {  
          var index = currIndex + d;

          if (index < 0) {
              index = totalImg - 1;
          }
          else if (index >= totalImg) { // totalImg = 4
              index = 0;
          }

          //console.log(index);             // see what happens 
          currIndex = index;
          var Img = imgArr[currIndex]; // looky here??            
          $slider.attr("src", Img);
          $slider.fadeIn(100);
      },
      forwardsGo: function () {

          $slider.fadeOut(100, function () {
              sliderCentral.nextImage(1);
          });
      },

      backwardsGo: function () {

          $slider.fadeOut(100, function () {
              sliderCentral.nextImage(-1);
          });
      },
```

Answer (score 0):

There was some issues with the advancing and retarding the `currIndex`.

```
     forwardsGo: function() {                  

            $slider.fadeOut(500, function () {              
            var nextIndex = (currIndex+1 > totalImg)?0:currIndex+1;  //new
            var currentImg = imgArr[nextIndex];        //amended          
                $slider.attr("src", currentImg);             
                sliderCentral.nextImage(1);                   
            });  
      },

      backwardsGo: function() {

            $slider.fadeOut(500, function () {
            var prevIndex = (currIndex-1 < 0)?totalImg:currIndex-1; //new 
            var prevImg = imgArr[prevIndex];    //amended            
                $slider.attr("src", prevImg);  
                sliderCentral.nextImage(-1);                              
            }); 
      },
....
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/moob/5TsL6/4/